# Extrema of ab + ac + bc - abc if a + b + c = 1

Tags: inequality, contest-math

a, b and c are three non-negative real numbers such that a+b+c=1.
What are the extrema of
ab+bc+ca-abc?

I know by AM-GM that $ab + bc + ac \geq 3a^{2/3}b^{2/3}c^{2/3}$ and again by AM-GM $1 \geq 3a^{1/3}b^{1/3}c^{1/3}$ but I'm guessing there is a clever way to write an expression involving the 3 terms, which we can then use AM-GM on in order to solve. Any insights would be appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hint:

$$ab+bc+ca-abc=(1-a)(1-b)(1-c)-1+(a+b+c)$$

Spoiler:

(Upper bound)

> You're given $a+b+c=1$ and $a,b,c$ are non-neg reals, so they must be in $[0,1]$ and thus $1-a, 1-b, 1-c$ are non-neg reals. Apply AM-GM for upper bound.

(Lower bound)

> The lower bound is clearly $0$ for the given conditions since the expression is non-negative with $0$ attained at $(1,0,0), (0,1,0)$ and $(0,0,1)$

Comment: Here's an interactive [3D graph](https://sagecell.sagemath.org/?z=eJyNT0FOwzAQvPsVo3KxUzd1WqSiCn-h4h5FKCSxaqmNozhAktezGwoHOIAlz65nZ2blunFwctSY1FGAzgyLDBuMdKeF8Y7IR5gj-mZ47VucytMyiCQdkwlrwplwItwwk8zL_CaPQtS0pfpjzX_TkGB3wBYPQlx9y658CdZf_1BwoQe38K3IpdEwSoNrxjXjd1EI8dLW5P7kxRO13SUM-1o6DRrdgLnnLvh2iDbbGS2qcAm9lRWplvZadjE9xzeKDl1Z-WGyJj1w4JoS2UiRucy2e9rD4L57pQqN6OfG3t_C7OrOGbP64eZ__hYa41iYxnN4l-oDA7B3cQ==&lang=sage), with the extrema marked.

Answer (score 1):

Prasun Biswas has a nice answer ,here is a generalised approach which is more uglier but can serve as a good method with similar problems

Let $u=ab,w=a+b$ also  $w\le a+b+c= 1$

by AM_GM we get $0\le u\le \frac{w^2}{4}$

we have to get extrema of $$ab+bc+ca-abc=ab(1-c)+c(1+b)=wu+(1-w)w$$ let $$f(u)=wu+(1-w)w$$ indeed its a lenear function in $u$ so our extrema will be at the endpoints ie when $u=0,u=w^2/4$ also as $w\ge 0$ the function has a positive slope hence $$\min f(u)=f(0)=w(1-w)\ge 0 \tag {when w=0,1}$$    $$\max f(u)=f(w^2/4)=\max(w^3/4+w-w^2)= \frac{8}{27}$$ $$ \iff \frac{w^3}{4}+w-w^2-\frac{8}{27}=\frac{(3w-8){(2w-3)}^2}{108}\le 0$$

Comment: What do you mean by the "endpoints"?

Comment: @Yashuppot226  the boundary conditions as $u\in[0,w^2/4]$ we have to check only those extereme values